# TeXmacs not available (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: software-installation

I used GNU TeXmacs very often for maths related stuff for university. Now completely wiped my old Ubuntu installation and directly installed Ubuntu 15.10 from disc. After installing all updates I tried

```
sudo apt-get install texmacs
```

The terminal said it was no longer available. Then I tried manually installing it with instructions on the official website, but after I was done, I still couldn't start it. I also tried uncommenting all repos in `sources.list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is not available anymore, that's right. You can install the [Vivid packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=vivid&searchon=names&keywords=texmacs).

1. Re-enable the repositories in `sources.list`
2. Download, e.g. for 64-bit

   ```
   cd
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/texmacs-extra-fonts/texmacs-extra-fonts_0.2_all.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/texmacs/texmacs-common_1.0.7.18-1_all.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/texmacs/texmacs_1.0.7.18-1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Install

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i texmacs*.deb
   ```

Possibly there are some missing dependencies but that is no problem, just execute the command in the next step.

3. Install the missing dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did all as you said, but the program still doesn't show up in my applications list... (I'm sorry but I'm not that experienced with Ubuntu)

Comment: Some error messages during the installation?

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy texmacs`

Comment: texmacs:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     1:1.0.7.18-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Do you have the downloaded files?

Comment: Of course. I downloaded the archive and followed the steps on the site

Comment: `texmacs: Installed: (none) Candidate: (none) Version table: 1:1.0.7.18-1 0 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status ` says, it's not installed. Go in the folder, where the downloaded files are placed and start the installation again. Give me the full output of this procedure inclusive all commands here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Oh I'm dumb... It works already, however I have to go to the installation directory in the console and type texmacs &

Answer (score 4):

Texmacs is no longer available in Ubuntu repos because it depends on Guile-1.8 which is considered deprecated by Debian (and hence not in the repos anymore).

However TeXmacs is still being developed and current .deb packages for all recent Ubuntu versions are available at [opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:slowphil:texmacs-devel](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:slowphil:texmacs-devel&package=texmacs) which is more or less like a PPA, except it's not Ubuntu-exclusive.

These .deb files are far easier to install than the static package available at texmacs.org mentioned in chaskes' answer; they are also much more recent with many bug fixed. For instance input methods based on ibus work with the debs but are broken in the static package.

Answer (score 3):

You can also download the current [TeXmacs binary file](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/download/unix.en.html) .

Unpack the zip file to a directory of your choice. Then follow the installation instructions, which just involve setting the proper paths:

```
Set the environment variables.
Let [installation directory] be the current directory,
which contains this file. Depending on your shell, either type

   setenv TEXMACS_PATH [installation directory]
   setenv PATH $TEXMACS_PATH/bin:$PATH
or
   export TEXMACS_PATH=[installation directory]
   export PATH=$TEXMACS_PATH/bin:$PATH
```

After that, TexMacs ran fine, although there were a few warnings about missing fonts.

One advantage of using the binary is that is provides the newest `TeXmacs 1.99` while Vivid and Trusty use `1.0.7`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I already tried that one and still can't see the application show up in the app list...

Comment: It won't show up in the app list automatically. You need to start it from the unzipped folder. You can make a .desktop file and put it in /usr/share/applications or, better, ~/.local/share/applications. I'll add this to the answer shortly.

Comment: Where is the desktop file? ;)